# Laravel returning JSON response with extra ` ' ` quote: " ' {"status":500,"m

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm using jQuery `$.ajax` to send ajax requests to my Laravel 5.1 API.

I'm trying to simply output the error response from the server, but am unable to `JSON.parse` the response due to a rogue `'` at the beginning of the `responseText` property value.

Why is that there?

[image]

**Frontend**:

```
API.Auth.register(params).done(function (result) {

    // Do stuff

}).error(function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('Registration error: ', xhr);
    var parsed_response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log('parsed_response', parsed_response);
    alertify.error('There was a problem with your registration.');
});

register : function (params)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: globals.env.api_host + globals.env.api_ver + '/register',
        type: 'POST',
        data: params,
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: true
    })
},
```

**Laravel 5.1**: I've tried wrapping the properties in `" "`, with the same error result:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $new_user = $this->create($request->all());
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        // error code 23000 is unique SQL unique constraint error - TODO: abstract this checking
        if ($e->getCode() === '23000') {
            return response()->json(['status' => 500, 'message' => 'This e-mail already exists. Try a new e-mail or logging in.']);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['status' => 500, 'message' => 'There was an error processing registration.']);
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT**: I tested if the `'` persists if I just return a string:

```
    //Original Route:
    //$router->post('/register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

    $router->post('/register', function () {
        return 'hello world';
    });
```

Response: `'hello world`

That single quote at the beginning persists.

---

**Side note:** I can't find anything on capturing a custom Exception message in jQuery ajax. My preferred way to return errors is custom exceptions:

```
throw new BadRequestHttpException('There was an error processing registration.');
```

but `$.ajax` offers no way to capture the exception message, so I've resorted to returning `response()->json...` from Laravel.

Any thoughts on this?

---

**EDIT: Found it.** Someone made an accidental change to the `config/app.php` file and added a `'`. Odd how Laravel treats this though by still serving the response, but prepends the `'`.

[image]

Comment: inspect the response headers and $.ajax errro handler arguments for status text

Comment: @charlietfl https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#json-responses says that `response()->json` (which I'm using) already sets the header type to `json`. I checked the status text in the ajax response and it has that rogue ` ' ` single quote in it. See above

Comment: if send a  400 or 500 series status code can get response message in ajax error handler

Comment: I would also like to point out that you don't need `response()->json()` anymore - returning an array will display json.

Comment: @Derek thanks - hmm. Any thoughts on where that rogue `'` single quote is coming from at the beginning of the response: `-->'<--{"status":"500","message":"There was an error processing registration."}`

Comment: @Growler - it might be somewhere that an echo is occuring (maybe some debugging etc) does it happen if you create a route and just return some json there?

Comment: @Derek see above plz. Yes is the answer

Comment: @Growler - if you have source control, you should start looking through all the recent commits.

Comment: Also, if you don't have source control, you could do a `grep` command for the text `"'"` in all files.

Comment: @Derek found it. See above

Comment: @Growler sweet - and anything outside of php tags is considered output, so that's why it is "prepended" (when actually, it's there because it was typed, not being added by laravel or even php)

Comment: @Derek really cool to know and a good lesson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a lot of searching, @Derek suggested I check source control for rogue additions such as `'` single quote.

I found someone had accidentally committed a `'` to the config/app.php file.

[image]

PHP treats anything outside the `<php>` tags as output, hence why it was being "prepended" to any response.

This was breaking `JSON.parsing` on the frontend obviously because the response payload was malformed JSON.